# (How) Can the owner of a Github repository access IP addresses of collaborators?

Tags: git, github, ip-address

I am the owner of a private github repo. I have a number of collaborators. Someone who I've recently invited as a collaborator has expressed concern over the fact that the invitation acceptance screen says I'll be able to see their IP address. I have been unable to find any way to view the IP addresses of my collaborators.

What is it that may allow me to see their IP address?

Is there some setting I can disable so that I wouldn't be able to view their IP address?

Comment: *GitHub* can certainly see their IP addresses. If you ran your own server systems you could see them directly. I don't believe GitHub *pass those addresses on* to people who host repositories *on* GitHub, but I don't really pay close attention to this sort of thing. If you (generic "you") want to hide your IP address, use a VPN.